# How to separate a line of input into multiple variables?

Tags: c++, file, parsing

I have a file that contains rows and columns of information like:

```
104857 Big Screen TV  567.95
573823 Blender         45.25
```

I need to parse this information into three separate items, a string containing the identification number on the left, a string containing the item name, and a double variable containing the price. The information is always found in the same columns, i.e. in the same order.

I am having trouble accomplishing this. Even when not reading from the file and just using a sample string, my attempt just outputs a jumbled mess:

```
string input   = "104857 Big Screen TV  567.95";
string tempone = "";
string temptwo = input.substr(0,1);
tempone += temptwo;
for(int i=1 ; temptwo != " " && i < input.length() ; i++)
{
  temptwo = input.substr(j,j);
  tempone += temp2;
}
cout << tempone;
```

I've tried tweaking the above code for quite some time, but no luck, and I can't think of any other way to do it at the moment.

Comment: can you make changes in file and add column seprator something like 104857 | Big Screen TV | 567.95 ...it will be easy afterwards .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the first space and the last space using [`std::find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) and [`std::find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) . You can use this to better split the string into 3 - first space comes after the first variable and the last space comes before the third variable, everything in between is the second variable.

Answer (score 0):

How about following pseudocode:

```
string input = "104857 Big Screen TV  567.95";
string[] parsed_output = input.split(" "); // split input string with 'space' as delimiter

// parsed_output[0] =  104857
// parsed_output[1] =  Big
// parsed_output[2] =  Screen
// parsed_output[3] =  TV
// parsed_output[4] =  567.95

int id = stringToInt(parsed_output[0]);
string product = concat(parsed_output[1], parsed_output[2], ...  ,parsed_output[length-2]);
double price = stringToDouble(parsed_output[length-1]);
```

I hope, that's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well try breaking down the files components:

- you know a number always comes first, and we also know a number has no white spaces.
- The string following the number CAN have whitespaces, but won't contain any numbers(i would assume)
- After this title, you're going to have more numbers(with no whitespaces)

from these components, you can deduce:

grabbing the first number is as simple as reading in using the filestream `<<`.
getting the string requires you to check until you reach a number, grabbing one character at a time and inserting that into a string. the last number is just like the first, using the filestream `<<`

This seems like homework so i'll let you put the rest together.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a regular expression, something along these lines:

```
^([0-9]+)\s+(.+)\s+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$
```

I am not very good at regex syntax, but `([0-9]+)` corresponds to a sequence of digits (this is the id), `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)` is the floating point number (price) and `(.+)` is the string that is separated from the two number by sequences of "space" characters: `\s+`.
The next step would be to check if you need this to work with prices like ".50" or "10".